# Find Automorphism Group if the following graph (Picture below)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, automorphism-group

I'm studying for an exam and found the following task concerning Automorphism Groups:

"Find the Automorphism $Aut(G)$ Group of the following Graph $G$."
[image: Graph]

On the outside, the graph looks like a regular pentagon, which would be an easy task. I figured out, that $Aut(G)$ doesn't contain any rotations since the middle part wouldn't be isomorphic. I think I have found one isomorphism, which results in mirroring $G$ on the central vertical axis. This would be the permutation $(24)(9 10)(56)(78)$. I can't find any other isomorphisms, which is hard to believe for me since this task gave 4 out of 40 points on last years exam.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Can you give the definition of the automorphism group please?

Comment: @FareedAF Find all isomorphisms of the graph to itself.

Comment: It seems to me that the key is that vertices $5$ and $6$ are the only ones of degree $2$, so they must be fixed or swapped.  Also their neighbors, vertices $2,8,4,7$ must be mapped among themselves.  It looks like once the images of these $6$ vertices are known, the automorphism, if there is one, is determined.  So, you can approach it systematically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I$ be the identity isomorphism, and let $M$ be the mirroring isomorphism. We want to determine whether there exist any other isomorphisms.

In order to do this, let's imagine that there exists an isomorphism that I'll denote $F_1$ which is unequal to either $I$ or $M$. Let's see what we can learn about $F_1$; maybe we will be able to prove a contradiction, or maybe we will be able to find a construction of $F_1$.

An isomorphism must respect the valences of vertices. There are exactly two vertices of valence $2$, namely vertex 5 and vertex 6, and therefore $F_1$ either fixes 5 and 6, or $F_1$ interchanges them. Define a new automorphism $F_2$:

- Case 1: if $F_1$ interchanges $5$ and $6$ then $F_2 = M F_1$ fixes $5$ and $6$;
- Case 2: if $F_1$ fixes $5$ and $6$ then $F_2 = F_1$.

Either way, we have produced an isomorphism $F_2$ that fixes $5$ and $6$.

Furthermore, $F_2$ is different from $I$ (because in Case 1, if $F_2=I$ then $M_1 F_1 = I$ and so $F_1 = M_1^{-1}=M_1$; or if $F_1=F_2=I$; and in either case we get a contradiction).

Next, I look in the graph for all paths between $5$ and $6$. There is just one path of length $3$, namely 5---8---7---6. An isomorphism must take paths to paths and must respect lengths of paths. Therefore $F_2$ take this path to itself and it also fixes the endpoints, and it follows that $F_2$ fixes $7$ and $8$.

Since $F_2$ fixes $5$ it must either fix both $2$ and $8$ or interchange them, but we've just shown it fixes $8$ so it also fixes $2$. By a similar argument $F_2$ fixes $4$.

I think you should probably be able to continue from here, showing that $F_2$ fixes $1$ and $9$ and $10$, and therefore $F_2 = I$. This is a contradiction, and therefore $F_1$ did not exist.